# Fetching Selected value from a dropdown list in Angular 8

Tags: angular, forms, drop-down-menu

Am working on a Single Page Application using Angular 8 on the frontend and Laravel on the backend. I have got a form which has input text field and a dropdown list. The values on the text input fields are being captured well on the typescript file but am having a problem **capturing the value selected from the drop down list** so that I can submit on the backend..

~ Kindly assist?

**Create.component.html**

```
<form #createForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Child SurName</label>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="childSurName" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="childSurName" 
            placeholder="ChildSurName"
            [(ngModel)]="form.childSurName">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="child-gender">Child Gender</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="childGender" name="child-gender" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled> Child's Gender</option>
            <option value="Male"> Male</option>
            <option value="Female"> Female </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" 
                [disabled]="!createForm.valid">Save Details </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Create.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthCheckService } from 'src/app/Services/auth-check.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})

export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  public form = {
    childSurName: null,
    child-gender: null
  };

  public error = null;

  constructor(
       private Auth:AuthService,
       private router: Router,
       private AuthCheck : AuthCheckService) 
  { }

   //Submit form data to the backend via a function in he service file
   onSubmit(){
    this.Auth.submitFormData(this.form).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the `<select>`

```
[(ngModel)]="form.childGender"
```

Also for consistency rename the key of your form to:

```
public form = {
   childSurName: null,
   childGender: null
};
```

Here's a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uh9xsf) for the same. (Note that on submit only the form is being logged to the console)

Comment: Ok.,,, Just a clarification,, the default text for the dropdown field seems not to be showing..

Comment: by default assign a value in your ts as follows: `form.childGender = 'Select Gender'` or try the below method 

`<option value="" style="display:none"> Child's Gender</option>
            <option value="Male"> Male</option>
            <option value="Female"> Female </option>
        `

Comment: @BearNithi Thanks alot,, please assist on the question on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845886/cross-component-communication-on-a-single-page-application-in-angular-8)  , am a beginner in Angular..

Comment: @Nicholas ,, Thanks alot,, Kindly assist me on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845886/cross-component-communication-on-a-single-page-application-in-angular-8)

Answer (score 3):

`[(ngModel)]` directive seems to be missing on your `select` element.