# Cross-Component communication on a Single Page Application in Angular 8

Tags: angular, components, single-page-application, communication

Am working on a Single Page Application using Angular 8 on the frontend and Laravel on the backend. After capturing the data from a login form then submitting to the backend via JWT which works fine. Later I get a response 
on the logic file of the form (login.component.ts) from the backend.

Now am trying to pass the response from the login component to another component via a shared service called AuthCheck.Finally I pass the data to the Navbar Component file and finally display it on the view. Basically cross-component communication.

In the service am using rxjs for listening to the response and setting an observable.Next am trying to assign my data to a variable in the service which I listen to in the Navbar component logic file and display on the navbar view..

The problem is that I keep getting an error of **ERROR TypeError: "this.AuthCheck.checkUser is not a function"** which is thrown from the login component

~ Kindly assist?

**Login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';
import { TokenService } from 'src/app/Services/token.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthCheckService } from 'src/app/Services/auth-check.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public form = {
    email: null,
    password: null
  };

  public error = null;

  constructor(
    private Auth:AuthService,
    private Token:TokenService,
    private router: Router,
    private AuthCheck : AuthCheckService
  ) { }

  //Submit the form data to the backend
  onSubmit(){
    this.Auth.login(this.form).subscribe(
      data => this.handleResponse(data),
      error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }

  //Function to listen to the response
  handleResponse(data){
    //Pass the data to checkUser method in AuthCheckService
    this.AuthCheck.checkUser(data.user);
  }

  //Handles any errors
  handleError(error){
      this.error = error.error.error;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**AuthCheck Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthCheckService {

private userName = null;

    private userName = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.checkUser());
    checkUser$ = this.userName.asObservable();

    checkUser(data: any){
        this.user = data;
        this.userName.next(this.user);
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

**Navbar Component ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthCheckService } from 'src/app/Services/auth-check.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  public userName : string;

  constructor(
    private AuthCheck : AuthCheckService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.AuthCheck.checkUser$.subscribe(message => this.userName = message);
  }
}
```

**Navbar Component (Markup file)**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" *ngIf="loggedIn">Welcome {{ userName }}</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried renaiming your checkUser method in the AutCheck Service to a different name. Your problem could be caused by the attribute in that service with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a property and a method with the same name (`checkUser`) change it as follows:

change the `checkUser` to `checkUser$`. You should also set the `BehaviorSubject` to the `userName`. Please uncomment the line

**AuthCheck Service**

```
//private userName = null;

//Check logged in userName
private userName = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Martin');
checkUser$ = this.userName.asObservable();


checkUser(data: any){
    this.user = data;
    this.userName.next(this.user);
}
```

**In your navbar component**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.AuthCheck.checkUser$.subscribe(message => this.userName = message);
}
```

Comment: I have added your first code block in my AuthCheck service and I get this error:

Comment: share me the error. hope you updated your navbar component as well with `checkUser$`

Comment: I get this error:  ERROR TypeError: "this.userName is null"  when the page loads,, I have also edited the code snippet as how you advised,, please check it out ..

Comment: you should have to change this line `this.userName.next(message);` to `this.userName.next(this.user)`. or share me what data do you receive in your `this.user` property. I have updated my answer as well

Comment: ,, The data I receive in this.user is a string which is the name of the logged in user,,

Comment: Okey, then update the code as i suggested. It'll work.

Comment: I have updated the code and reedited my code of how am using it,, I get this error when page loads :  ERROR TypeError: "this.userName is null" which is thrown from the AuthCheck service,,

Comment: why did you comment this line `private userName = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Martin');` in your AuthCheck?, uncomment it.

Comment: I was using it to pass static data from AuthCheck service to Navbar component,, Now I wanted the data to be dynamic,,should come from the login component then to AuthCeckService then to Navbar compoonent

Comment: Just uncomment that line and remove `private userName = null`. bcz, `next()` method will only work on `Subjects`.

Comment: Okay,, I have tried,, am passing the function this way to the behaviourSubject `private userName = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.checkUser());  checkUser$ = this.userName.asObservable();` Seems incorrect from my console as I get this error..

Comment: @Belhi,, Thanks Alot   or help and patience..I have figured it out